# Transfer animation from armature to mesh with keyframes

Tags: animation, armature, bezier-curves, shape-keys

Soo this is quite a complex problem, I've got to a point where I got close to solving this problem but I got stuck here.

First of all, I have an animated armature with a stickman attached to it (its bodyparts are literally made of edges). The reason for the edge part is that later I want to separate every edge, in this case body part, and convert it to curves. So I have an animation, I could export it as a .mdd, and then reimported it to the base model (stickman) without the armature. This way the animation works fine, but all of the movements are controlled by shapekeys. Before converting the edges to curves I want to set the origin to geometry for all body parts, but that messes up the animation, and I guess the reason for this is that the animations are not real keyframes, rather keyframe controlled shapekeys. Setting it to the geometry would be really important for me later.

I guess I would have to somehow convert/apply every shapekey to keyframes but this is where I'm stuck, I have no idea if that's even possible.
I know this whole text can be really confusing, I tried my best to describe the problem.